# BroadcastReceiver keep getting data when unregisterd

Tags: android, android-broadcast

i register my BroadcastReceiver when Navigation Drawer is shown and unregister it when it is closed.

When it's closed the BroadcastReceiver still gets the data that was sent even it is unregisterd.

this is what I did:

```
        private BroadcastReceiver dataUpdateReceiver;

        boolean drawerClosed = true;

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            // unregister the reciver
            if (dataUpdateReceiver != null)
                getActivity().unregisterReceiver(dataUpdateReceiver);

            drawerClosed = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to
                // prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).commit();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()

            drawerClosed = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
            if (drawerClosed) {
                // register the reciver before the drawer open
                if (dataUpdateReceiver == null) {
                    dataUpdateReceiver = new DataUpdateReceiver();
                }
                IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Constants.BROADCASTRECIVER_TO_ACTIVITY);
                getActivity().registerReceiver(dataUpdateReceiver, intentFilter);

                // update running timers
                ((NavigationDrawerListAdapter) mDrawerListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
```

and here i'm getting the data:

```
private class DataUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public DataUpdateReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
        long millisUntilFinished = intentExtras.getLong(Constants.INTENT_TIMER_TIME_IN_MILLS, 0);
        int timerCode = intentExtras.getInt(Constants.INTENT_TIMER_CODE, 0);

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.BROADCASTRECIVER_TO_ACTIVITY)) {
            NavigationDrawerListAdapter adapter = (NavigationDrawerListAdapter) mDrawerListView.getAdapter();
            int position =adapter.getPositionByTimerCode(timerCode);
            updateView(position, millisUntilFinished);

            if (millisUntilFinished > 0 )
                setClearRuningText(position);
        }
        Log.i("test", "test");

    }

}
```

When I log it I get "test" also when the drawer is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your drawer closes, you are registering the receiver again in `onDrawerStateChanged()`:

```
@Override
public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
    super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
    if (drawerClosed) {

        // ...

        getActivity().registerReceiver(dataUpdateReceiver, intentFilter);

        // ...

    }
}
```

I recommend moving the `registerReceiver()` call to `onDrawerOpened()`.

Also be aware that `onDrawerStateChanged()` is likely being called far more often than you expect. It isn't just called when the drawer goes from open to closed or closed to open; it is called every time the motion state of the drawer changes. Thus every time the drawer goes between the idle, dragging, or settling state, this method is called again.